# Simplify checking "null or empty" for multiple variables in IF statement

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, null, conditional-statements

I have two string variables in validation function which should ensure that variables won't be null or empty at the same time (also the case when one is null and other equals to empty, is not allowed).

Current IF statement is very complex as I have to check:

1. if both are null
2. if both are empty (if their lengths are equal to 0)
3. if string1 is null and string2 is empty
4. if string1 is empty and string2 is null

It is functional but ugly and not "best practice". How can it be simplified?

```
if ((string1==null && string2==null) || (string1.length==0 && string2.length==0) || (string1==null && string2.length==0) || (string2==null && string1.length==0))
```

Comment: You could make use of [type coercion and falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy): `if (string1 && string2) { ... }`

Comment: Put scenario aside, I gave enough info and I hope my question is clear. Just need best practice approach to simplify this long if condition.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution would be to check these conditions in order. First check against `null` then check if the strings aren't `empty` and to do it the best way would be to compare the string to an empty string which will avoid getting Exceptions if you use `.length` on `undefined`.

So use `if(string1 === '')` instead of writing `if(string1.length==0)`.

**Solution:**

Then you can simply use the following condition:

```
if (!string1 || !string2 || string1 === '' || string2 === ''){
     //Your code here
}
```

**Explanation:**

It will be `true` if one of the two strings is `null` or `empty`, in other words if any of the four conditions is `true` it will enter the if block.

Comment: I thought !string1 also checks for string1 !== ''

Comment: @DylanHunt If `string1 = ''`, `!string1` gives `true`, while `str !== ''` gives `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check one variable first if `null` or empty and than the other and join both result with AND.

```
if ((string1 === null || string1 === '') && (string2 === null || string2 === '')) {
    // both null or empty
}
```

If you have only other truthy values, you might use

```
if (!string1 && !string2) {
    // both falsy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function for readability, like:

```js
function isEmpty(param){
  if(param==null || param.lenght==0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

var string1, string2;

//And you if becomes:
if(isEmpty(string1) || isEmpty(string2)){
  //[...]
  console.log('String1 & String2 are empty');
}
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write a helper function:

```
function stringIsNotValid(val) {
    return val == null || val.length == 0;
}

if(stringIsNotValid(val1) && stringIsNotValid(val2)) { ... }
```

But a simplified if could be

```
if((string1 == null || string1.length == 0) && (string2 == null || string2.length == 0))
```

Comment: Really !! I think you should switch your conditions to avoid exceptions on `string1.length` and `string2.length`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.